# Avast anti virus exclude files

Tags: anti-virus, avast, exclude

I have a cracked program and i need avast to exclude the crack from scanning as it read it as virus How can i make avast anti virus to exclude some file to be scanned as it always read those files virus and delete them

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't support using cracked programs.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the free version of Avast, you will have to go to settings from the left menu list, then go to General and then scroll down until you see Exclusions. There you can set a whole folder or just a file. Be careful with hacks and such because they sometimes can have a virus. Yes, manu of them are false positive, but still, be careful.